# How is setTimeout() implemented such that it can keep track of the time elapsed without blocking the main thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

Given a `setTimeout` call of

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hello')
}, 1000)
```

you know that your code will run in >= 1000ms.

However, if JavaScript is single threaded, how does the `setTimeout` call keep track of the amount of time elapsed in a non blocking fashion?

I know the fundamentals of the event loop, and understand that after that x amount of time the callback is passed onto the callback queue; however, what I don't understand is how setTimeout is able to keep track of time in the background without slowing down the execution thread.

Even if it's run concurrently (not parallel), and made use of some sort of scheduler wouldn't it screw with the performance of the rest of your code that's running synchronously?

Comment: [`Event loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: @RayonDabre this isn't helpful. I've already read this article, but it does  not explain how setTimeout works behind the scenes. How do you implement a non blocking timer?

Comment: It's implemented by node.js, not the js engine itself.

Comment: Though is is `non-blocking`, but it remains in the `queue`..

Comment: @KevinB by environment do you mean it's a call to the OS?

Comment: sorry, i worded that incorrectly. Basically, setTimeout isn't part of javascript, instead it's something that is added to it by whatever is implementing it. for example, all web browsers add it, and node.js adds it. They also don't implement it exactly the same way. in node.js for example, setTimeout returns an instance of `Timer`, where as in the browser it returns an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is implemented by node.js and isn't an actual part of javascript. This allows it to break the rules a little bit. There's no way in javascript to delay the execution of code without blocking the main thread, therefore the environment that wraps the JS engine implements setTimeout to give us that functionality.

Comment: That's what I figured, but it didn't seem to be documented anywhere at all. Thank you! Not sure why you got downvoted...seems like someone doesn't like this question :p